# awk - separate by 1 column by condition in loop

Tags: bash, awk

Dear all I need some help.

I have this input file:

```
 chr1
 chr1 
 chr2 
 chr2 
 chr3 
 chr3
```

I would like to separate it into the following output files:

"1st file"

```
chr1
chr1
chr1
```

"2nd file"

```
chr2 
chr2
```

"3rd file"

```
chr3
chr3
```

I am using this code but it is not working

```
for i in {1..3}                 
do 
    awk '{if ($1 == "chr"$i) {print $0}}' 17_n.tsv > $i 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `awk` is a separate language with it's own interpreter, `bash` variables can't be used properly in `awk` without passing them first using the `-v` option.  Also, the default action in `awk` is to print, so you don't need `{print $0}`.

So this would work:

```
for i in {1..3}                 
do 
    awk -v i=$i '$1 == "chr"i' 17_n.tsv > $i 
done
```

That said, you can also accomplish what you want in a `read` loop:

```
while read -r line
do
    [[ $line == chr+([0-9]) ]] && echo $line >> ${line#chr}
done < 17_n.tsv
```

Comment: Ohhh, man thank you, I forgot on one of the most  important thing and it is calling variable from bash to awk, thank you.... it works...

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  Here is some more [useful information](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use something like this:

```
$ cat file
 chr1
 chr1
 chr2
 chr2
 chr3
 chr3
$ awk '{suffix = substr($1, length($1)); print > "file" suffix}' file
$ cat file1
 chr1
 chr1
$ cat file2
 chr2
 chr2
$ cat file3
 chr3
 chr3
```

Basically, take the last character of the first field and use it to determine the filename.

If there can be more than one digit at the end, you can use this instead:

```
awk 'match($1, /[0-9]+$/) { print > ("file" substr($1, RSTART)) }' file
```

`match` sets `RSTART` to the position of the start of the match, so it can be used with `substr` to extract the numerical part of the input.

Comment: Yes it is nice , but I have in input file chr1..chr22,so I will receive files, where will be in one file chr2,chr22.chr12...

Comment: In that case, Kent's suggestion is ideal.

Comment: @Filip I have added an alternative implementation that would handle multiple digits.

Answer (score 1):

if your lines are in format `N non-number chars + N numbers`, you can try:

```
awk '{f=$0;sub(/^[^0-9]*/,"",f);print >("output"f)}' input
```

this won't work for `ch0r1`.

If you want it to work for `ch0r1` too, use **gawk**:

```
awk '{f=gensub(/^.*[^0-9]([0-9]*)$/,"\\1","g");print >("output"f)}' file
```